# How to use the output of the 'script' command in a pipe with sed

Tags: sed

Following [this answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833) I'm trying to use the 'script' command to unbuffer output for use with a pipe. But it's not working as I'd expect.

I have the following file:

```
$ cat test.txt
first line
second line
third line
```

Now, when I run two following two commands I expect their outputs to be the same, but they are not:

```
$ cat test.txt | sed -n '{s/^\(.*\)$/\^\1\$/;p;}'
^first line$
^second line$
^third line$

$ script -c "cat test.txt" -q /dev/null | sed -n '{s/^\(.*\)$/\^\1\$/;p;}'
$first line
$^second line
$^third line
```

The output of the first command is the expected output. How can the output of the second command be explained?

Comment: did you tried other solutions listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `script` is emulating a terminal it converts linefeed characters (`\n`) to carriage return/linefeed sequences (`\r\n`). OTOH, sed interpretes carriage returns as part of a line and inserts '$' after it. Then when this is output to a terminal, it interprets carriage returns by moving cursor to the start of the line and continuing output there.

You can see this by piping output to `hexdump -C`. First compare `cat` and `script` output:

```
$ cat test.txt | hexdump -C
00000000  66 69 72 73 74 20 6c 69  6e 65 0a 73 65 63 6f 6e  |first line.secon|
00000010  64 20 6c 69 6e 65 0a 74  68 69 72 64 20 6c 69 6e  |d line.third lin|
00000020  65 0a                                             |e.|
00000022

$ script -c "cat test.txt" -q /dev/null | hexdump -C | cat
00000000  66 69 72 73 74 20 6c 69  6e 65 0d 0a 73 65 63 6f  |first line..seco|
00000010  6e 64 20 6c 69 6e 65 0d  0a 74 68 69 72 64 20 6c  |nd line..third l|
00000020  69 6e 65 0d 0a                                    |ine..|
00000025
```

Then compare output piped through `sed`:

```
$ cat test.txt | sed -n 's/^\(.*\)$/\^\1\$/;p;' | hexdump -C
00000000  5e 66 69 72 73 74 20 6c  69 6e 65 24 0a 5e 73 65  |^first line$.^se|
00000010  63 6f 6e 64 20 6c 69 6e  65 24 0a 5e 74 68 69 72  |cond line$.^thir|
00000020  64 20 6c 69 6e 65 24 0a                           |d line$.|
00000028

$ script -c "cat test.txt" -q /dev/null | sed -n 's/^\(.*\)$/\^\1\$/;p;' | hexdump -C
00000000  5e 66 69 72 73 74 20 6c  69 6e 65 0d 24 0a 5e 73  |^first line.$.^s|
00000010  65 63 6f 6e 64 20 6c 69  6e 65 0d 24 0a 5e 74 68  |econd line.$.^th|
00000020  69 72 64 20 6c 69 6e 65  0d 24 0a                 |ird line.$.|
0000002b
```

So, when `script | sed` outputs this to a terminal:

```
$first line
$^second line
$^third line
```

This is what happens:

1. "^first line" is output, cursor is at the end of the line
2. "\r" is output, cursor moves to the start of the line (column 0)
3. "$" is output, overwriting "^" and moving cursor to column 1
4. "\n" is output, moving cursor to the next line, but leaving it in column 1
5. "^second line" is output starting from column 1 (no character at column 0 at that moment), cursor is at the end of the line
6. "\r" is output, moving cursor to the start of the line (column 0)
7. "$" is output at the column 0, moving cursor to column 1
8. "\n" is output, moving cursor to the next line, but leaving it in column 1
9. and so on

If you still want to use `script`, remove `\r` characters. Like this:

```
script -c "cat test.txt" -q /dev/null | sed -n 's/\r//; s/^\(.*\)$/\^\1\$/;p;'
```

Note, that you will still see "staircase" output on the terminal even though the sed output is alright. I'm not sure why that happens, probably `script` is modifying terminal settings. The "staircase" effect disappears, if you pipe the output through "cat", for example.

Comment: I'll add hexdump to my regular tool set, thanks!
This rewrite works:
`script -c "cat test.txt" -q /dev/null | dos2unix | sed -n '{s/^\(.*\)$/\^\1\$/;p;}'`

Comment: Thanks for that. I indeed do like to use `script`. I simplified the question a bit here. Instead of a file I actually have the output of a certain command (stdout&stderr) that I want to pipe to `sed`. `script` helps to combine the two output streams in the correct order by disabling buffering, so `sed` receives the same input as shown on the screen when running the command.

Comment: @Joost I would recommend using `stdbuf` instead. You won't have the '\r' and "staircase" effect problems this way. Like this: `stdbuf -o0 -e0 command 2>&1 | sed`

Comment: That's not available on the system I have to use. That's why I went with `script`. But maybe I'll try to compile it locally.

Comment: In this case `unbuffer` from `expect` is likely available. It doesn't add '\r' nor it modifies terminal settings. You can use it like this: `unbuffer command | sed`. It might be in a separate package from `expect` itself. At least on Debian it is in `expect-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 script -c"cat test.txt |sed 's/.*/^&$/'" -q /dev/null
```

or better still:

```
 script -c"sed 's/.*/^&$/' test.txt" -q /dev/null
```

N.B. the entire `script` is passed to **script**.